# mount.cfs asks for password when passing argument -o guests

Tags: centos, mount, cifs

I have Centos machine that want to mount files from NAS, but when passing guest user, it want password:

```
mount.cifs //192.168.96.2/b/files/ /mnt/files -o guests,nocase
```

In another machine near this virtual machine which is centos, it mounted successfully.

Even added this /etc/fstab :

```
//192.168.96.2/files /mnt/files cifs nocase,username=guests,password= 0 0
```

And saw the boot log:

```
localhost mount: mount error(112): Host is down

localhost mount: Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

localhost systemd: mnt-files.mount mount process exited, code=exited status=32

localhost systemd: Failed to mount /mnt/files.
```

What's the problem?

Comment: still no answer? just watching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found that I should mount with option -o vers=1.0